# What is the best css selector for 'all children'?

Tags: class, css

On my page - in my css I have put:

```
*{pointer-events:none;}
.pev{pointer-events:auto}
```

This is because I want a strong ui and there are some draggable things i don't want users accidentally selecting things, etc

**So I am taking away all clicks,hovers etc and just putting them back on things that need to be touched**

i have an element **(classed .play)** that holds a youtube player (given it's parent the prev class and jquery draggable).

I would like to know the proper most efficient way to bypass .prev and * and just add pointer-events auto to the player and anything inside it via inheritance (I think this is correct)

Which of these is better syntax?

```
.play*{pointer-events:auto;}
.play < *{pointer-events:auto;}
```

**UPDATE----------------------------**

Thanks to [Pinal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2525067/pinal), I have been able to stabilize the pointer-events (if the cursor happens to interfere with the video when dragging the pointer events of the video would normally stop the drag event eg the mouse moves faster than the dragged element then a stall in dragging will happen.. Result === UI looks broken).

so here is the simple fix (thanks again man)...

css:

```
*{outline:none;pointer-events:none;}
.pev{pointer-events:auto!important;}
.play > * {pointer-events:auto;}
.playdrag > * {pointer-events:none!important;}
```

jquery:

```
$(document.body)
    .on('mouseover','.play',function(){
        $('.play').draggable({ containment:'#screensize',scroll:false});
        })
    .on('mousedown','.play',function(){
        $(this).addClass('playdrag');
        })
    .on('mouseup','.play',function(){
        $(this).removeClass('playdrag');
        });
```

So very cool, makes everything smooooooooth!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misprints, you forgot about spaces and children selector is `>`, not `<`:

```
.play * {pointer-events:auto;}//select all inside
.play > *{pointer-events:auto;}//select children only
```

So better use `.play > *` for only children selection.

Comment: I'm dyslexic lol I thought really long about (<>) and was determined that I was right LOL! So the spaces are crucial? ah because there is no . or # so a space and lack of class/id would be to show that we are talking about html tag type... Thank you Pinal

Comment: @BENZ.404 the spaces are not crucial, but the `>` direction. You can write also `.play>*{ /*works*/ }`

Comment: oh cool! which one do you think is best though, less characters means less load, but does it mean more browser work?

Comment: `less characters means less load` - GZIP will take care about traffic for you. Don't make your code unreadable.